# How to go one step back in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, frameworks

I have been trying to add a file that is NOT present in current directory using '..'(Double Dotts).

But it shows complete_url/../scripts/style.cssstyle.css?ver=4.6.1' ..

```
 $wp_easy_seo_scripts =plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'../scripts/style.css';
```

why it is showing double dot .. in output too ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use .. when you have the complete path using

```
    plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) it will give you path to your plugin dir
```

after that you can add

```
  '/scripts/style.css';
```

so it becomes completely like this

```
 $wp_easy_seo_scripts=plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/scripts/style.css';
```

hope this will solve your issue

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Why not...

```
$wp_easy_seo_scripts ='/path-to_directory/scripts/style.css';
```

Keep in mind, the path-to-directory will be from your www/public_html directory (document root), so you should not need those directories in the path.. but just in case, if you do, it might look something like this

```
$wp_easy_seo_scripts ='/home/user/www/path-to_directory/scripts/style.css';
```